# Constructor mismatch for Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to create my first Custom Adapter to generate a listview for my android app. I am getting my data from an Api call and then process it and store it in an arraylist:-

```
class Person{
    String bioguide;
    String image;
    String lastname;
    String firstname;
    String district;
    String state;
    String party;}

public static ArrayList<Person> personData = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Now in the onpostexecute section I am trying to create a listview and custom adapter to display my data as follows:-

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state_listView);
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(ByState.this, R.layout.bystate_itemview,personData);    
            yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);   
        }
    }
     public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {    
        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }    
        public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Person> items) {
            super(context, resource, items);
        }    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
            View v = convertView;    
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.bystate_itemview, null);
            }    
            Person p = getItem(position);    
            if (p != null) {
                TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
                TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.first_name);    
                if (tt1 != null) {
                    tt1.setText(p.getLastname());
                }    
                if (tt2 != null) {
                    tt2.setText(p.getFirstname());
                }
            }    
            return v;
        }    
    }
}
```

I got the above code following some internet tutorial. The thing is I am getting an error in the line where I use the customadapter first to invoke the constructor of custom adapter. It says cannot resolve constructor. Can someone help me in understanding this. I know I have not defined the proper constructor for my case please let me know the changes. I am creating the listview inside a fragment and the fragment class name is ByState.

Comment: use RecyclerView, more featured stuff. http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

In second line replace

```
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(ByState.this, R.layout.bystate_itemview,personData);
```

by

```
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(ByState.this, R.layout.bystate_itemview, personData);
```

You create your own adapter class, but invoke standart ArrayAdapter

Comment: But the constructor is using context and if I give ByState.this it still gives error.

Comment: @Anirban i dont know from your code, what is ByState. If this is not Context or Activity, then found it and use as first parameter

Comment: ByState is a fragment

Comment: @Anirban then use ByState.getContext() instead ByState.this